# WDS PXE client boot getting error: 'Windows Deployement Services: PXE Boot Aborted'

Tags: deployment, windows-server-2012-r2, wds

Created a new WDS (VM) server, installed WDS role, added boot/install image from Win7 Pro SP1 x64 volume license disc. Client I am booting is 64-bit but then I get this:

```
Downloaded WDSNBP from 192.168.1.10 WDS.contoso.com

Press F12 for network service boot

Windows Deployement Services: PXE Boot Aborted
PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM
```

- Client PC is Optiplex 3020
- [Intel Core i5-4590](http://ark.intel.com/products/80815/Intel-Core-i5-4590-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz)
- Realtek RTL8151GD (per Dell; Hardware ID: PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---**EDIT:** Default WDS settings (Properties, Boot) dictate you have to hit F12 (quickly) to continue booting, otherwise you will get PXE Boot Aborted. I am sure this is designed so that a boot order with NIC/PXE 1st will still boot to local devices without user intervention

> WDS log *(Source Deployment-Services-Diagnostics, Event ID 57347)* advised: The PXE server processed a request from a client of architecture x86.  However there were no boot images installed for this architecture

It seems either my NIC/PXE-code or BIOS is providing an invalid response to the architecture. Maybe its based on the processor on the NIC, I am not an engineer so I can't say for certain. However [per microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725614%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#Banned):

> Each computer that will be booting from the network should have DHCP option 93 to indicate the client’s architecture. This enables a PXE server to know (at boot time) the exact architecture of the client from the first network boot packet. **On many x64-based computers, the architecture value either is not set or is not set to the expected value. Generally, this means that the architecture is specified as x86-based but the computer is x64-based**

[This article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/configurationmgr/archive/2011/01/05/troubleshooting-the-pxe-service-point-and-wds-in-configuration-manager-2007.aspx) refers to a System Center component, however if you search for x86 *(the 6th iteration)* it advises you should have a x86 and x64 boot image. I guess you can FORCE it to boot a x64 (this may cause you trouble in the future) by opening WDS, right-clicking server, Properties, Boot tab

Answer (score 0):

A while ago we had similar issues 'Windows Deployement Services: PXE Boot Aborted'. In our case the problem was way simpler - some of our new laptops had that fancy '[F Lock key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-Lock)' functionality i.e. you need to press Fn + F12 to activate F12.